# Facebook Graph API v2.11 Getting users photos from their albums

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Been gone from FB sdk for a couple years now and just now getting back into it again for a project I am working on.

I've been looking over the new API documents and, correct me if incorrect, but it seems that FB no longer allows you to pull your **friends photo's** from their albums? Is this correct or am I overlooking something here?

I'm getting my access token by using the JS code to login and I'm able to query my own photos, friends, etc but once I place a **friends ID** into it instead of **/me** it does not show anything other than maybe their name and id even when I place the following into the graph query:

```
/{FBFriendIDHere}?fields=id,name,profile_pic,photos{link,likes{id},updated_time,picture,album,images}
```

Do each of my friends I am needing have to access my fb app and click the button to **approve the permissions** *before* I am able to pull anything on their profile now even when we are already fb friends?

Comment: no data at all from user profiles without permission. you can just use /me instead of the friend id, because it will only work for users who authorized your app with the correct permissions.

Comment: Yes, each of your friends will have to log in to your app and grant it permission to access their photos. // All `friends_XY` permissions, that allowed sharing friend’s data with an app, have been removed with API v2.0

Comment: @CBroe Does that mean they have to grant the app permissions **each time** they use the app or just once?

Comment: Once, unless they remove it again.

Comment: @CBroe Could you provide an official answer to my question and possibly an example of doing this correctly?

Comment: Any help with that example @CBroe?

Comment: Examples for the basic stuff like login, asking for permissions, ... are in the docs. If you try something based on that and encounter specific problems, we can discuss those further.